# Angular 4: marking an entire component as dirty

Tags: angular

I have a component with many input elements. I am aware that I can use `ng-model` and `ids` to access properties such as `dirty` and `pristine` ([as per the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms)).

However I'm wondering if there's an easier way to set the `dirty` property at the component level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically wrap your HTML elements in a Form, and that form would be set to dirty. I mean, if you want your component to be marked dirty, you could just create a property called 'dirty' but I'm not sure that would buy you anything.